# Run Powershell script that lives in TFS source control

Tags: tfs, powershell-2.0, tfsbuild

I'm trying to run a Powershell script during my build process, but I can't figure out how to access the ps1 file which is checked into source control (TFS 2010).  There is a similar SO question that exists, but I'm actually not sure if it's correct:

[TFS 2010: run powershell script stored in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278804/tfs-2010-run-powershell-script-stored-in-source-control)

My TFS source control is setup as such:

=Project
==BuildScripts
===MyScript.ps1
==Code
===Dir1
====MySolution.sln

I thought passing something like `SourcesDirectory + "\..\..\MyScript.ps1"` (to tell Powershell where the script is) would work, but I think I'm off somewhere.

Can someone help me figure out how to reference the ps1 file, and run it?

Comment: Yes the other answer looks perfectly correct.

Comment: @DaveShaw, I updated my question with my source control structure, and hopefully made what I'm asking a little more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to have a Workspace setup in your Build Definition that includes the directory with the Powershell script.

So your mapping might be like:

```
*Server*                    *Workspace*
$/Project/Code/Dir     -    $(SourcesDir)
```

You will need to add:

```
*Server*                    *Workspace*
$/Project/Code/Dir     -    $(SourcesDir)
$/Project/BuildScripts -    $(SourcesDir)/BuildScripts
```

Your InvokeProcess can then pass `Path.Combine(SourceDirectory, "BuildScripts", "MyScript.ps1")` to the Powershell command line.

N.B. You could also set the `$/Project/Code/Dir` workspace to `$(SourcesDir)/Code`.

Comment: yup, that was it...  I did not have a proper workspace setup for the BuildScripts directory.  Thanks again!